# excel vba dir function to find doc not docx

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this vba code in excel to get file names from a specific folder:

```
Sub getfilelistfromfolder()
Dim varDirectory As Variant
Dim flag As Boolean
Dim i As Integer
Dim strDirectory As String


strDirectory = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
i = 1
flag = True
varDirectory = Dir("C:\Users\USER\Documents\*.doc", vbNormal)
Range("A2:A100").Select
Selection.ClearContents

While flag = True
    If varDirectory = "" Then
        flag = False
    Else
        Cells(i + 2, 1) = varDirectory
        varDirectory = Dir
        i = i + 1
    End If


Wend
End Sub
```

However, I only want to get .doc NOT .docx.

How can I modify this code to get .doc file only?

*Note*: this is an example that I gave. My real file extension are our program-specific filetypes: .out and .outreview
I want to get the list only for .out files and **not** .outreview files.
example file names:

**file1.out

file2.outreview

file3.out

file4.outreview**

I want to list .out files only.

thanks

Comment: Well, if you'd followed the same `*.out` instead of `*.out*` or `*.*`, you should get only out files. However without seeing your real code and some file names it is hard to get the right answer.

Comment: @PaulFrancis: added example file names. otherwise, i think my question is very clear.

Comment: I never said your question was unclear. Sometimes, the logic you follow might not actually what your code dictates your compiler to do. So it is best to provide the actual code. The PSEUDO code you gave will only give the .doc not .docx

Comment: @PaulFrancis: the code is EXACTLY the same that I use. I put .doc in the example code which is .out in my own code. The reason I replaced it is for SEO purposes of the site, so that future users could easily find this question. If I had put .out and .outreview in the title, nobody would ever type in these unknown file extensions. These extensions are only used in our privately-owned software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just test for the desired extension:

```
Sub getfilelistfromfolder()
    Dim varDirectory As Variant
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strDirectory As String
    Dim Desired As String

    Desired = ".doc"
    i = 1
    flag = True
    Range("A2:A100").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    While flag = True
        If varDirectory = "" Then
            flag = False
        Else
            If Right(varDirectory, 4) = Desired Then
                Cells(i + 2, 1) = varDirectory
                i = i + 1
            End If
            varDirectory = Dir
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

It would seem that the dir function silently ignores extensions longer than three characters and treats them as if they were three characters (it uses the 8.3 char DOS name - maybe it's using some older Windows API), much like the DOS dir command would, try `dir /X *.doc` in a command prompt.

A workaround could be to test the extension, something like this should work:

```
IF (UCase(Right(varDirectory, 3)) = "DOC")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the reference to the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" (Menu Extras -> References), you can use the FileSystemObject:

```
dim fso as FileSystemObject
dim folder as Scripting.Folder
dim file as Scripting.File
dim extension as String 

set fso = new FileSystemObject
set folder = fso.getFolder("C:\Users\USER\Documents\")
extension = ".doc"

for each file in folder.Files
    if Right(file.shortname, 4) = extension then
        ' do stuff
    end if
next file
```

Please note that the `file.Type`-Attribute yields expressions like "Word Document", which can be different on different PCs and languages.

Comment: You can use late-binding to avoid having to set the reference.   And the technique of testing each file specifically for the correct extension can also be used with the OP's original method.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the respective lines of **code to search for file extension with ".Doc" only**; with following line/lines.

```
If UCase(Right(Trim(varDirectory), 4)) = ".DOC" Then
'Your Code here
End If
```