# How do I specify "EOL" in a VBA search string?

Tags: vba, search, ms-word

[Using VBA in Microsoft 365 Word]

In VBA, I am attempting to enumerate over all files in a directory with the .doc extension. However, there may be .docx files in the directory. Using the command

```
strFile = Dir("C:\Users\conrad\Desktop\*.doc", vbNormal)
```

unfortunately also catches the .docx files, which I do not want.

How do I keep from catching the .docx files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808372/excel-vba-dir-function-to-find-doc-not-docx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Dim fPath, pattern, f

fPath = "C:\Files\"
pattern = "*.doc"

f = Dir(fPath & pattern, vbNormal)
Do While f<>""
    If f Like pattern Then
       'is a .doc file
    End If
    f = Dir()
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

(Probably overkill, but...)

You can use `Scripting.FileSystemObject` to do this. Make sure to *add a reference* to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" under *Tools* > *References*.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    Dim fold As Folder
    Set fold = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\conrad\Desktop\")
    
    Dim f As File
    For Each f In fold.Files
        If FSO.GetExtensionName(f) = "doc" Then
            ' do whatever with the file
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```