# VBA merge xls file without xlsx file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to merge all workbook with xls extension only. But this code will merge xlsx file together, How can I solve this problem?
One more question, I want to merge these file into a new workbook. When I use  `Set wb = Workbooks.Add`, this code will create a new workbook but not merge inside it. All of the merge file will merge in my first workbook, I wan them to be appear in my new workbook.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MergeWorkbooks()
    Dim Path            As String
    Dim FileName        As String
    Dim WS              As Worksheet
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
   
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Path = "C:\Users\Name\Documents\"
    FileName = Dir(Path & "\*.xls", vbNormal)
    Do Until FileName = ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Path & "\" & FileName)
        For Each WS In wb.Worksheets
            WS.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Next WS
        wb.Close False
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: To restrict the work to only xls-files, add a simple If - `If Right(Filename, 4) = ".xls" Then`... To write the result to the specified workbook, and not to the workbook containing the macro, specify the target book in the `After:=` instead of the ThisWorkbook keyword

Comment: `Path & "\*.xls"` will not return any `xlsx` files. ``Path & "\*.xls*"`` will. Have you stepped through it to verify what you think is happening? Try using `Debug.Print FileName` inside of your loop to verify the filename of each file.

Comment: @braX Believe it or not, I also wanted to write that `Dir("*. xls")` does not return xlsx, xlsm, xlsb and others. But before writing - I checked. Unfortunately this is so - Dir() does not stop at the letter `s`

Comment: Hi braX , I tried it already, but I also not sure what cause to this problem. Hi JohnSUN , thanks for the code, it work fine.

Comment: @JohnSUN - very odd... you are right - seems to work the same with HTM and HTML - this must be a recent change (maybe windows 10 only?). unfortunate. Maybe a change with extensions over 3 characters?

Comment: @braX No, this is not Windows 10 - I have a different OS. Most likely, this is a change in the office - either a bug or a future.

Comment: looks like some info on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28808372/excel-vba-dir-function-to-find-doc-not-docx Looks like a FileSystemObject can differentiate between short and long filenames?